# Which formula to use for the finding the arrangement of men and women?

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables

There are 5 men and 5 women.

P(X = 6)  defines the arrangement of men and women where the highest ranking women is in the sixth position.

The formula that I would use is when the objects are partially distinguishable: 
$$\frac{n!}{n_{1}!n_{2}!n_{3}!...}$$
where $n_1$, $n_2$, etc... are the categories (i.e: $n_1$ for men and $n_2$ for women)

normally the answer would have been found by doing $$\frac{10!(total)}{5!(men)5!(women)}
$$

However in the textbook solution they do this:
$$\frac{5!5!}{10!}$$

why?

---

Now we want P( X =  5) (Highest Ranking women in the 5th position)

The textbook solution says that we have 5 available position that we must fill with 4 women. Therefore,

$$\dfrac {\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}5!5!}{10!}$$ Why do we have a combination mixed in with arrangements. For what reasons do we need the arrangement?

Comment: 1. I don’t quite understand the problem; what does “highest ranking woman” mean? Are the women ranked? Or does it mean that the first woman to occur occurs in the 6th position? 2. I don’t understand the answer you say the textbook gives. Are you trying to count things? Because $5!5!/10!$ is not an integer (it’s $1/252$), so that cannot be the count of anything. What *exactly* are you trying to compute? A probability, perhaps, given the use of $P$?

Comment: In the answer to the second question, shouldn't the numerator be $\binom{5}{4} 5! 5!$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first question: How many arrangements are there where the men are in spots 1-5 and the women are in spots 6-10? You can construct such an arrangement by making a sequence of two decisions: 1) Choose the ordering for the men ($5!$ choices) ; 2) Choose the ordering for the women ($5!$ choices). By the multiplication principle for counting, the total number of possible arrangements with men in spots 1-5 is $5! 5!$. On the other hand, the number of possible arrangements of these ten people, with no restrictions, is $10!$. So the probability that a random ordering of the ten people will have men in spots 1-5 is $5!5!/10!$.